# Passing Labels without Segues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

SceneA -> SceneB -> SceneC -> SceneD

How would I pass the value selectedValue, from sceneA to sceneD

1. without storing variables in all the other scenes
2. -> are segues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way for that is you can use `NSUserDefaults` for that, you can store it like this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(YourVariable, forKey: "YourKey")
```

after that you can access it from any `viewController` like this:

```
var returnValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YourKey") as? String
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the correct architecture, one would pass the value from SceneA to B, then to C and finally to D. 
However, if you aren't glad with that, you can take several courses of action.

Directly, SceneA can only pass data to SceneB. Of course it can't directly pass data to SceneD, because it doesn't exist yet. 
So either on creation, SceneD can get the list of currnet UIViewControllers in the UINavigationController and get to SceneA and access the selectedValue. 
Or you can have a singleton class behaving as some sort of 'dataManager'. SceneA should save value in it. And SceneD should get value from it.

Answer (score 1):

1.**NSUserDefaults**

You can store the variable in `NSUserDefaults` .You can save by following code (Objective C , you can easialy convert it to swift)

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:obj forKey:@"Key"];
```

and you can retrieve by

```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"];
```

2. **Appdelegate**

You can just save and retrieve your object in Appdelegate variable and use it anywhere by following

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```